# WMI ExecNotificationQuery Need Administrator Privileges to Query for Win32_ProcessStartTrace but not for __InstanceCreationEvent

Tags: c++, wmi, wmi-query

When I attempt to make a call to ExecNotificationQuery with query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace" I get a WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED Error code returned.

If I instead make the query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent" The query returns successfully.

However if I run my program as administrator then both of these queries return successfully.

I have 2 questions related to this

1. Why does one class require Administrator privileges and the other doesn't
2. In the future how can I discover what WMI class queries will require admin privileges without having to test them I can't see anything on the class documentation about restricted access

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After further attempts to understand WMI events:

The difference here comes down to the where the event comes from.

`__InstanceCreationEvent` is an intrinsic event which means it's defined by and sent by WMI in reaction to changes in WMI's data model, these are accessible to non elevated users.

`Win32_PorcessStartTrace` on the other hand is an extrinsic event, Extrinsic events are defined and sent by entity's external to WMI in this case that's the Windows Kernel Trace Provider which provides the `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` event. When an event provider like the Windows Kernel Trace Provider defines extrinsic events it supplies access information to specify who can access these objects.

So to answer question 1): Because the Windows Kernel Trace Provider has defined it that way

To answer question 2): I have yet to experiment with it myself but probably by calling `GetSecurityInfo()` on the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` retrieved from the queried event object, and inspecting the DACL(discretionary access control list).